# Mongo classes not autoloading in Yii console application

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, console

I am using Yii & mongodb(YiiMongoDbSuite extension), and created a console application. But its not working giving the error,

> include(Mongo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>       in file /var/www/yii/framework/YiiBase.php at line 418

I have configure the console.php to include all the modules, components and models. But still giving the error.

Comment: You have to edit the php.ini used for console and add the extension line there too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Mongo` class is a part of php mongo extension, it is not related to YiiMongoDbSuite. This means that mongo php extension is not loaded. Make sure, that your cli php is using proper (or any) `php.ini`. You might have defined ini path in `httpd.conf`, but it is used only by apache.
Easiest fix is to drop `php.ini` into your php folder.

Comment: Thanks @PeterM, i changed the php.in at /etc/php5/cli. and i got the extension loaded.

Comment: thanks you, just add extension=mongo.so in /etc/php5/cli and sudo service apache2 restart, then mongo loaded in php CLI

Answer (score 0):

Open path : **/etc/php5/cli** then open php.ini and add extension **extension=mongo.so** restart apache service your issue is resolved.