# Yii 1.2 framework command line Migrate file not run?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

> PHP Error[2]: include(MongoClient.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory     in file /var/www/yii/framework/YiiBase.php at line 427

After proper installation of **Mongo 2.4.9** version.
**PECL** extension is also installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo classes not autoloading in Yii console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521910/mongo-classes-not-autoloading-in-yii-console-application)

Answer (score 0):

Add `extension=mongo.so` in `/etc/php5/cli` and do a `sudo service apache2 restart`.